# Qt/C++ call function on extended QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt based program, I have a hierarchy like so:

MyApplication::QMainWindow -> QTabWidget -> ProjectWidget::QWidget

In MyApplication I have a traditional menu, and one of the actions is to import, and needs to call a ProjectWidget->importStuff() as defined by QTabWidget->currentWidget.

The problem I'm having is when I use QTabWidget->currentWidget I'm limited to the subset of QWidget functions, I cannot call any of the extended functions. I also don't know how to set up a SIGNAL/SLOT that will only affect the single ProjectWidget (without triggering the rest of them)

I'm thinking of adding a property to all the ProjectWidgets called "isCurrent", then I'll set a signal that will call the import, and check the "isCurrent" state. If it's the current widget, then it will execute the import function. But this seems convoluted, is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two straightforward options

You can use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) static method to invoke any invokable method, all you need is a `QObject*` pointer and the method name (and parameters, if there are any). To make method invokable, either use [`Q_INVOKABLE`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE) macro in your subclass definition, or simply make the method into a Qt slot. Then you need just the `QObject` pointer, and can (try to) call any method with any arguments (and get error if no such method exists).

Another way is to use [`qobject_cast<>()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast), which tries to cast a *QObject* subclass pointer to another, and will return `nullptr`, if it can't be done (object is not of that class). And once you have the right pointer type, just call any method you like. It is much like standard C++ `dynamic_cast<>`, but works only for QObject subclasses, because it uses the Qt meta-object system and does not depend on C++ RTTI.

Note: these two ways are something you should use when there is no nice way to have a separate, GUI-independent way to access the widget. But in your case here, these seem to make things so much simpler, it is justified, as long as you plan to keep the `QTabWidget` around for the lifetime of the app.

---

Code example from comment of OP, on using the `invokeMethod` way to solve this exact problem:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(myTabWidget->currentWidget(), "callbackFunction");
```

This has the benefit, that now it is possible to have two `QObject` subclasses which are otherwise unrelated, and just have invokable method with same name (not overriden version of a common superclass method), and the method can be called. There's no need to have the class definition available at compile time, and *there is no need to add a common base class or introduce an abstract interface class and use multiple inheritance*. This is basically like duck typing: if `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(ptr, "quack")`, then it is a duck.

Downside is then that *there is no compile time type checking*, simple typo in the method name string can make the code silently fail. So it's important to think (and implement and comment in code, and test) what to do when the `invokeMethod` fails at runtime (is it a bug, or a normal situation for some UI states?). But then this applies to (Qt4 syntax of) `QObject::connect` too, as many Qt programmers have learned the hard way, when slots did not get called because of a typo :-).

Comment: (sorry for lack of links to Qt docs, writing from tablet on the road, will add links to answer tomorrow...)

Comment: Thanks Hyde, I managed to hunt down the appropriate docs. I like method #2 in this instance - I do agree passing the pointer is ideal, but in this case forcing more dependencies to that specific class seems undesirable. There's only a few QActions in the main window which need to talk to the projects, so even if it's less elegant I'm willing to settle for one 'ugly' component in favour of an overall cleaner design. ++ Excellent advice.

Comment: (Just caught the edit / Update) Works perfectly, I'll be updating my question with the solution for future readers.

Comment: @Kver just accept the answer, at Stack Overflow you shouldn't edit to add the answer to the question.

Comment: Alright. But for the aforementioned future readers, here's the line of code the solution ultimately led to: 
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(myTabWidget->currentWidget(), "callbackFunction");

Comment: @kver If you have some extra notes or clarification to question, you can add those by editing the question, or by adding a comment, or even editing the answer or adding comment to answer (like you commented this answer). Indicate good answers by accepting what helped you best, upvoting any good ones, downvoting when answer is wrong or otherwise very bad.

Comment: I was just explaining why I chose the invokeMethod option instead of passing the pointer; it was just about keeping the classes separate and from becoming dependant on eachother. But, methinks now that's probably best left for another question or more topical overview on code guidelines/advice.

Comment: @Kver Added the links, and (what I think is) your reasoning for using `invokeMethod` instead of `qobject_cast`, and also the downside.